# Can i call getMediaUrl method in template file with a default block instance?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, catalog, layout, blocks

In my custom phtml file (say foo/bar.phtml file), i need to call $this->getMediaUrl(some/imagefile), How do i use $this instance with a default block instance(say core/template).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the base media path, **you'll need to concatenate** - to get the base:

```
Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . '/your/file/path.jpg';
```

This **differs from other methods** of getting fully-qualified urls, for instance, if you want an image you've uploaded to the skin folder (not media folder), you pass the file name:

**Non-secure:**

```
$this->getSkinUrl('image.jpg');
```

**Secure URL**

```
$this->getSkinUrl('image.jpg', array('_secure'=>true));
```

Comment: The approach Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . '/your/file/path.jpg'; works when i prepended 'catalog/product' to '/your/file/path.jpg'.

Comment: I used: Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'your/file/path.jpg';